# Can a vim mapping trigger an Autohotkey macro?

Tags: vim, macros, autohotkey

I would like to trigger an Autohotkey macro using a vim mapping, is this possible? For example, to create a normal mode vim mapping in vim to enter <kbd>CTRL-J</kbd>, then use that to trigger Autohotkey.

In vim:

```
:nnoremap ,w <ctrl-j>
```

Autohotkey

```
^j:: do something
```

When I do this, physically typing <kbd>CTRL-J</kbd> on my keyboard successfully triggers the Autohotkey macro, but the vim mapping does not.

Answer (score 1):

Since AutoHotkey listens to actual keyboard events and is not aware of what goes on internally on any specific application, and since Vim's mappings are not actually sending new keyboard events when they trigger, no.  You can create an AutoHotkey macro that is specific to Vim only:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx
#IfWinActive, - G?VIM\d*$
:*?:`,w::
    do something
    return
#IfWinActive
```

But this has the disadvantage of triggering regardless of Vim's mode, since AutoHotkey can't know if Vim is in normal mode or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ImageSearch, as you know the coordinates of the VIM status bar where it says INSERT you can use a SetTimer to check every say 200ms if INSERT an be found (you have to capture / create an image first of course). If it can be found you can set a toggle variable to be true or false and you can use that toggle variable with #If statement.

Would look something like this

```
Toggle:=false
SetTimer, Label, 200
Return

#If Toggle
; hotkeys/hotstrings etc
#If

label:
IfWinNotActive, ahk_exe gvim.exe
   {
    toggle:=false
    return
   }
ImageSearch.... ; 
If (ErrorLevel = 0) ; image found
   {
    toggle:=true
    return
   }
Return
```

Comment: I see I misunderstood the question. I leave the answer above as it may be of some use for someone in the future but you want VIM to trigger AutoHotkey. Perhaps you can use :!<cmd> to run a script?